# My custom DialogFragment does not show in activity

Tags: android

i've followed and customized some of Android tutorials about DialogFragments, and here it is what I coded:

```
public class ChooseDialog extends DialogFragment {

ArrayList mSelectedItems;
CharSequence[] items;
boolean[] selected;


public static ChooseDialog newInstance(CharSequence[] options) {
    ChooseDialog f = new ChooseDialog();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putCharSequenceArray("items", options);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mSelectedItems = new ArrayList();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Choose")
            .setMultiChoiceItems(savedInstanceState.getCharSequenceArray("items"), null,
             new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton, boolean isChecked) {
                       if (isChecked) {
                           mSelectedItems.add(whichButton);
                       } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(whichButton)) {
                           mSelectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(whichButton));
                       }
                   }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Chosen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            });


    return builder.create();
}
}
```

I call in activity, which i want to show my dialog in:

```
CharSequence items[] = { "foo", "bar" };

DialogFragment newFragment = ChooseDialog.newInstance(items);
newFragment.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "somedialog");
```

It crashes, when it's up to call setMultiChoiceItems, because Bundle savedInstanceState is null. What should I do? Maybe can it be done more ellegant, cause i've just started learning Android development.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the savedInstanceState bundle isn't where your argument is stored.

the bundle you need is from getArguments();

so

```
savedInstanceState.getCharSequenceArray("items")
```

becomes

```
getArguments().getCharSequenceArray("items")
```

Comment: Silly mistake, thank you! :) Can you tell me about something else, what can I improve in my solution?

Comment: Not that I can see actually. It's quite novel actually generating the dialog using arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
public class DialogFragment1 extends DialogFragment{

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();
    return dialog;
}
}
```

And in activity

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(v);
        }
    });
```

showDialog

```
    public void showDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment fragment1 = new CopyOfTimePickerFragment1();
    fragment1.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
}
```